# Can "come to" mean "gradually"?

Tags: vocabulary

In sentences like:

> The scientists came to realize that they were opening up a worm can.
>
> I came to understand that he was lying to us all the time.

Can *come to* mean *gradually*? I have checked the dictionaries but have not found this sense up to now.

Comment: The whole phrase "came to understand" means that he gradually understood that. Of course, by itself the phrase "come to" does not have the meaning "gradually".

Comment: [related question on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/70420/48335)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction *'to come to + realise/understand'* means has roughly the same meaning as:

> To **come/begin/start to** + realise/understand

E.g: If *after a while (a period of time) you were beginning to realise/understand* someone was lying to you all the time, you could say:

> I **began/started/came to** realise/understand that he was lying to us all the time

Usually "came to/start to/begin to" **do imply** a gradual realisation or understanding, so gradually or after an extended period are good descriptions.